# Kotlin - create an object based on sum

Tags: kotlin

I have a question.
I have the following class

`data class Item(val month: Int, val year: Int, val value: Int)`

And I have a list

```
val items = listOf(
    Item(month = 1, year = 2019, value = 5000),
    Item(month = 1, year = 2019, value = 200),
    Item(month = 1, year = 2019, value = 300),
    Item(month = 1, year = 2019, value = 1000),
    Item(month = 2, year = 2019, value = 5000),
    Item(month = 2, year = 2019, value = 6000),
    Item(month = 3, year = 2019, value = 500),
    Item(month = 3, year = 2019, value = 1500),
    Item(month = 5, year = 2019, value = 900),
    Item(month = 1, year = 2020, value = 700)
)
```

I want to sum values of Item objects having the same month and year, and create another Item object with field month, year and sum as value

```
val result = listOf(
    Item(month = 1, year = 2019, value = 6500),
    Item(month = 2, year = 2019, value = 11000),
    Item(month = 3, year = 2019, value = 2000),
    Item(month = 5, year = 2019, value = 900),
    Item(month = 1, year = 2020, value = 700)
)
```

How can I achieve so? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you group by month + year (assuming that this should be unique). Then you map this to a new item in which the value is the values of each group.

`items.groupBy { "${it.month}/${it.year}" }` would give you something like this:

```
{
  '01/2019': [
    Item(month = 1, year = 2019, value = 5000),
    Item(month = 1, year = 2019, value = 200),
    Item(month = 1, year = 2019, value = 300),
    Item(month = 1, year = 2019, value = 1000)
  ],
  '02/2019': ...
}
```

This grouped map you now map to new items in which you recalculate the `value` using the sum of all items. The resulting code looks like this:

```
items.groupBy { "${it.month}/${it.year}" }
     .map {
            Item(it.value.first().month, 
                 it.value.first().year,
                 it.value.sumBy(Item::value))
        }
```

The result in my code looks exactly like your example output.

**Update:**

In order to avoid string creation and accessing the first array element, there's another approach. Create a data object you group by:

```
data class Date(var month: Int, var year: Int)
```

Now you group by the Date object you create on the fly - and also unpack the value:

```
    items.groupBy({ Date(it.month, it.year) }, { it.value })
```

This creates a map like this:

```
{
    { month: 1, year: 2019 }: [ 5000, 200, 300, 1000 ],
    { month: 2, year: 2019 }: [ ... ]
}
```

Afterwards, you can map this in a similar way as before, but with much cleaner member access:

```
items.groupBy({ Date(it.month, it.year) }, { it.value })
     .map {
         Item(it.key.month,
              it.key.year,
              it.value.sum())
     }
```

If you use this as base class for your item, you can also extend the reuse of the data class.

Answer (score 0):

### Get object sum based group by any key

```
val v1 = VARegenerate("1", "LA-1", 20)
val v2 = VARegenerate("2", "LA-1", 40)
val v3 = VARegenerate("3", "LA-2", 60)
val v4 = VARegenerate("4", "LA-2", 20)
val v5 = VARegenerate("5", "LA-3", 20)

val resultGroupBy = listOf(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5).groupBy { it.loanId}

print(resultGroupBy)

Ans:
LA-1=[VARegenerate(id=1, loanId=LA-1, amount=20), 
     VARegenerate(id=2, loanId=LA-1, amount=40)], 
LA-2=[VARegenerate(id=3, loanId=LA-2, amount=60), 
     VARegenerate(id=4, loanId=LA-2, amount=20)], 
LA-3=[VARegenerate(id=5, loanId=LA-3, amount=20)]}

val resultSumOfGroupBy =  listOf(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5)
                          .groupBy {it.loanId}
                          .map { it -> 
                           it.key to it.value.sumOf {it.amount  } }

 print(resultSumOfGroupBy)

 Ans:
  [(LA-1, 60), (LA-2, 80), (LA-3, 20)]
```